# Sparklyr Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am trying to run a Linear Regression (all the NA have already been removed from the data) using Sparklyr with a huge flight dataset, but I am getting the following Memory Error:

Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 33.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 33.0 (TID 327, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (...)

I am using the following code:

```
lm_model <- my_dataset %>%
  select(A, B, C, D) %>%
  ml_linear_regression(A ~ B + C + D)
```

Do you have any advice on how to avoid such error?

Answer (score 0):

Three things that might work.

1. If you have a lot of saved variables, vectors, datasets etc. Remove the ones you don't need.
2. Restart R session.
3. Allocate more memory to rJava by `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")`.